# Spring: best use of @Transactional and rollback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

In these two example, I used Spring+JPA+Hibernate. Which of two is the correct form?  In the first example MyException is unchecked instead in the second example MyException is checked. Thanks and sorry for my English

### First example

CartController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/buy",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String buy(){
  CartDAO.buy();
  return "redirect:/";
 }//buy
```

CartDAOImpl.java

```
@Transactional(rollbackfor=MyException.class)
public class CartDAOImpl implements CartDAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public void buy(){
 ....
 if(x !=y) throw new MyException();
 em.persist(Item);
 ....
}
}
```

ExceptionController.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public String articlenotavailable(){
    return "error/articlenotavailable";
}

}//ExceptionController
```

MyException.java

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

### Second Example

CartController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/buy",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String buy()throws MyException{
  CartDAO.buy();
  return "redirect:/";
 }//buy
```

CartDAOImpl.java

```
@Transactional(rollbackfor=MyException.class)
public class CartDAOImpl implements CartDAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public void buy()throws MyException{
 ....
 if(x !=y) throw new MyException();
 em.persist(Item);
 ....
}
}
```

ExceptionController.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public String articlenotavailable(){
    return "error/articlenotavailable";
}

}//ExceptionController
```

MyException.java

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend none of those. The transaction should be handled in a higher layer than dao e.g. service or even a higher layer.

Comment: I agree with Luiggi, although this is also a naming problem: what you name a DAO is in fact a service containing business logic, that should delegate its persistence operations to a DAO. A DAO would have find/create/update/delete methods, not a buy method. Regarding exceptions, a checked exception will get in the way. Since all you can and want to do is handle them in a top-level exception handler anyway, prefer an unchecked exception.

Comment: CartDAO contains , in addition to the method buy, the methods: addToCart,removeFromCart, updateQuantityArticle . For you , do I move the method buy? So, the best solution is with unchecked exception , is it right?

Comment: Can you correct the code and move the buy method? Thanks

Comment: All these are business methods. Your DAO should be renamed. And you should introduce a real DAO containing simple methods like findById(), create(), etc.

Comment: The cart is saved in http session and not in the database. Is this the same thing?

Comment: Is this the same thing?